# CentOS on WSL--typing too fast?

Tags: centos, terminal, windows, tty, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using zsh with WSL/CentOS.  I am somewhat of a fast typist, and WSL can be slow.  I am facing a weird issue where if I am running a command and begin typing the next command before the first command completes, the intermediate keystrokes do not get echoed at the next prompt, and tab completion does not work at the next prompt.  This does not happen on native CentOS, just CentOS running under WSL, so I figure it might have something to do with docker configuration.  Does anyone have any suggestions (something like readline config?) about how I can have CentOS/WSL buffer my keystrokes and then add them to the next command like Native CentOS does?

Comment: AFAIK WSL currently supports Ubuntu, Fedora and openSUSE. When did they add CentOS?

Comment: WSL-Switcher allows us to use CentOS.